# How to identify Core Data Managed Object Model -- hash?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, synchronization, nsmanagedobjectmodel

Is there a method to get a unique hash for a Core Data Managed Object Model, so that I can see if the core data store is up-to-date with a specific model? I am building a core data sync system, and I want to make sure that the core data stores which are being synced are using the same version of the managed object model.

Answer (score 1):

The model itself does not have a hash value, but

```
[managedObjectModel entities]
```

returns the array of entity descriptions, and each entity description has a `versionHash` property. You could compare these with the version hashes in the `metaData` dictionary of the persistent store.

But to check the compatibility of a store with a model you can also use

```
isConfiguration:compatibleWithStoreMetadata:
```

as described in ["Is Migration Necessary"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmCustomizing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004399-CH8-SW2)
in the "Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration Programming Guide".